# Use of canonical tag in HTML

Tags: seo

I read about canonical tags in  HTML and from what I understood it is used to help search engines to realize which is the original content. I have articles in my recently created blog, which I have pasted in certain other popular websites. In those websites I gave back a link to my original blog post with the canonical tag. But yet my blog page is not visible in search engines (other websites do show my article). Before I had pasted onto other websites, my articles were indexed on google and could be seen on the 1st page. So I guess, there is no problem on my SEO part.

Can someone please suggest a method where my original blog gets higher preference for the content?

Comment: check this http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cross domain canonical tags.

So if you have duplicated content on other domains you can use the canonical tag on those pages pointing back to the original page on your site.

This a great way to deal with syndicated content; of course you would need code level access on these other websites so you can implement the canonical tag.

More info below

```
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't just copy paste your articles on every place on the internet, that will not do you any good. After writing a good article go to other sites and write something else about your articles like what your article is about, how it is helpful to someone, something like that so that people and websites come to your website to read your article. For this you don't need "canonical"

If you copy paste articles to other websites, it will only create duplicate content issues and will only harm your SEO efforts.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not required for your Blog section to do canonical issue.
Canonical means Google displays same pages with different URL.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is not submitting your article in different websites I will not give you any benefit in your ranking. If you write a good and quality content you should post in only one website if you post in different sited google will consider as a duplicate content. So it's better for you you can share your approved blog link in social media sites and also do social bookmarking, microblogging. And after you don't need canonical tag.

Answer (score 0):

As @moobot said you can indeed use a cross-domain canonical tag to let Google know about the original source of the content. How exactly are you adding the canonical on other domains?

The canonical link should be in the head section of the html code. If you're adding it yourself somewhere in the body tag that's not going to do you any good.

Check out this article for some other common mistakes with the canonical tag
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html

@metadice mentioned that copying your content all over the web isn't good for your SEO and i agree completely. If you do this for some extra backlinks or something i would recommend you to stop doing this.

Hope my answer will help someone who has this same question.